# ERROR: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default in ui code

Tags: shiny

I keep getting this error with my code!

Can anyone help.

Thanks

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("T420 Tagging KI"),

    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput ("eartag", "Eartag", names(KITAGT420)),

    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
  )  

))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`mainPanel` should be outside `siderbarPanel` but inside `sidebarLayout`.

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("T420 Tagging KI"),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput ("eartag", "Eartag",names(KITAGT420))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          plotOutput("plot")
        )
        )))
```